# Restart cron job when connection restored

Tags: server, bash, scripts, cron

So I have a script that needs to be executed completely and that runs on a distant server. I wish to be able to handle the case where the server gets shut down when it was executing the script. In other words I would like to be able to restart the script automatically when the server is up again.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `/etc/rc.local`may be the place for that.